# attribute with same name but different scopes can be overridden or maintained?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In JSP what happened if two attributes added with same name but different scopes. When I try this code I got page scope attribute value as null and session scope value is as I stored.

```
   <%  pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "MCA", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
      pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "BSc", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and found expected results.

```
<% 
pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "MCA", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "BSc", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE); 
pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "Inter", PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE); 
%>
 attribute in page scope:       <%=pageContext.getAttribute("kumar", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE)%>
 attribute in session scope:    <%=pageContext.getAttribute("kumar", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE)%>
 again attribute in application scope: <%=pageContext.getAttribute("kumar",PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE)%>
```

Output

```
attribute in page scope: MCA 
attribute in session scope: BSc 
again attribute in application scope: Inter
```

Every scope is different. As specified in the comments already,there is no such thing override in high level scope and low level scope.For better understanding,see concrete implementation of getAttribute method in **org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl**

```
 private Object doGetAttribute(String name, int scope) {
         switch (scope) {
         case PAGE_SCOPE:
             return attributes.get(name);

         case REQUEST_SCOPE:
             return request.getAttribute(name);

         case SESSION_SCOPE:
             if (session == null) {
                 throw new IllegalStateException(Localizer
                         .getMessage("jsp.error.page.noSession"));
             }
             return session.getAttribute(name);

          case APPLICATION_SCOPE:
             return context.getAttribute(name);

         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid scope");
         }
     }
```

### See Also

- [Concrete Implementation of SetAttribute](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.jasper/com.springsource.org.apache.jasper/7.0.26/org/apache/jasper/runtime/PageContextImpl.java#PageContextImpl.doSetAttribute%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%29)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes with same names can be override if they are in same scope. You can see difference when call those attribute as follows:

```
  attribute in page scope:       <%=pageContext.getAttribute("kumar", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE)%>
  attribute in session scope:    <%=pageContext.getAttribute("kumar", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE)%>
  again attribute in page scope: <%=pageContext.getAttribute("kumar")%>
```

Comment: I adde one more attrbute with application scope with same name  like this pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "Inter",    PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);but  this attribute not overridden any of it's low level scope attributes, only page scope attribute overriden with session scope.  how is it possible.

Comment: No there is not such thing  to override atrribute in low level scope with higher scope which has same name . Even you remove attribute from application_scope it will not affect in lower scoper. Jsp allow you to have attribute with same name in different scope.

Comment: No boss, I am sure as said last comment, when print all 3 attribute values, page context attribute value got null, remain 2 are came correctly. plz test once  as I said. Here is my example code.

Comment: pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "BSc", pageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
     pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "MCA", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    pageContext.setAttribute("kumar", "Inter",
      PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

Comment: String bsc = String.valueOf(pageContext.getAttribute("kumar",
     PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE));
   String mca = String.valueOf(pageContext.getAttribute("kumar",
     PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE));
   String inter = String.valueOf(pageContext.getAttribute("kumar",
     PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE))